# Prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is a lattice then so is $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ in the uniform metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In Folland's real analysis (page 139), it states

> $X$ denotes a compact Hausdorff space and we equip the space $C(X)$ with the uniform metric. If $\mathcal{A} \subset C(X, \mathbb{R})$ , $\mathcal{A}$ is called a lattice if $\max(f, g)$ and $\min(f, g)$ are in $\mathcal{A}$ whenever $f, g \in \mathcal{A}$. Since the lattice operations are continuous, one easily sees that if $\mathcal{A}$ is a lattice, so is $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ in the uniform metric.

My attempt at the proof:

> Assume $\mathcal{A}$ is lattice, $f,g \in \overline{\mathcal{A}}$ with $\{f_n\}$, $\{g_n\} \subset \mathcal{A}$ s.t. $f_n\to f$ and $g_n\to g$ uniformly.
>
> Since $\mathcal{A}$ is lattice, $\max(f_n, g_n)$, $\min(f_n, g_n) \in \mathcal{A}$ for any $n$.
>
> **Want to show:** $\max(f_n, g_n) \to \max(f,g)$ and $\min(f_n, g_n)\to \min(f,g)$, so $\max(f,g)$, $\min(f,g) \in \overline{\mathcal{A}}$ hence $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ is a lattice.

Am I in the right direction? If so, would one help me with the **want to show** part?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use $\max(a,b)=\frac{(a+b)+|a-b|}{2}$ and $\min(a,b)=\frac{(a+b)-|a-b|}{2}$ and triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1):

As hinted by @NDB, we use the facts

> $$\max(a,b) = \frac{(a+b) + |a-b|}{2}$$
> $$\min(a,b) = \frac{(a+b) - |a-b|}{2}$$
> $$||a|-|b|| \leq |a-b|$$

Therefore,

> Given $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N_1, N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for $\forall n\geq N_1, \forall x\in X$ and $|g_n(x)-g(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for $\forall n\geq N_2, \forall x\in X$.
>
> Then given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N=\max(N_1,N_2)\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. for $\forall n\geq N, \forall x\in X$:
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> |\max(f_n,g_n)-\max(f,g)| &= \left| \frac{(f_n+g_n+|f_n-g_n|)}{2} - \frac{(f+g)+|f-g|}{2}\right| \\
> & = \frac{1}{2} \left| f_n - f + g_n - g + |f_n - g_n| -|f - g|\right| \\
> & \leq \frac{1}{2} \left(| f_n - f + g_n - g| + ||f_n - g_n| -|f - g||\right) \\
> & \leq \frac{1}{2} \left(| f_n - f| + |g_n - g| + |f_n - g_n - f + g|\right) \\
> & \leq \frac{1}{2} \left(| f_n - f| + |g_n - g| + |f_n - f| + |g - g_n|\right) \\
> & < \epsilon
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, $\max(f_n,g_n) \to \max(f,g)$. It is similar for $\min(f_n,g_n) \to \min(f,g)$.